# WP7 7.1 (Mango) Database Versioning

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I have a class structure that's saved to the local SQL DB on the phone. In the next version of the app, the class structure has changed.

How does the SQL DB deserialize the data into the changed objects/structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was listening to YapCast with Jesse Liberty and Sean McKenna mentioned there is an API for doing database upgrades for new data model versions.

[DatabaseSchemaUpdator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.data.linq.databaseschemaupdater%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)

Comment: Sean also mentioned this in his Mix'11 talk - DatabaseSchemaUpdater seemed pretty limited in what changes would support. For example added columns would be OK, but complicated schema changes wouldn't be.

Comment: Makes me wonder if objects should be versioned. As in, putting the model object into V1, V2, etc folders. Then you could load the old database and upgrade it using the new models.